# Why doesn't my bootstrap data toggle work in navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

Below I have code to create a simple consolable navbar with Bootstrap 5 with a logout button, the logout button does collapse into a data toggle but the data toggle doesn't work when you click it any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Document</a>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <button class="navbar-toggler ms-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <form name="logout" class="logout" action="PHP/Logout.php" method="get">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Log Out</button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For what are you using `jquery`?

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal I'm using it in the full version of the site and just left it in, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Try moving your jQuery and bootstrap js script tags to the bottom of the body tag.

Or, try adding this boostrap script CDN: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: This has to do nothing with his problem. Also what is the problem in the CDN he is using.

Comment: You need JQuery for bootstrap to work btw. I am not sure what the popper version is for.

Comment: At least do some research before posting. Bootstrap has dropped jquery.

Comment: Ok I thought he was using Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Just thought I would add, actually you don't need any javascript for bootstrap to work no matter the version. Its only if you need the features that are dependent upon javascript. I stopped using anything but the css years ago. The css is convenient for website responsiveness.

Answer (score -1):

I was using out of date code from the old docs (*facepalm*)

The code at this link works fine: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

New code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Document</a>
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <form name="logout" class="logout" action="PHP/Logout.php" method="get">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Log Out</button>
          </form>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```